# Is PHP blocking the sticky bit?

Tags: php, linux, file-permissions, chmod

I tried setting a permission with PHP's chmod to 02775. But for some reason it only added 0775 to the file. I thought it might be a problem with PHP's chmod implementation or something, so I tried running 'chmod 02775 path' using PHP's passthru() function, but I got the same result. I tried the same command in a shell and it worked perfectly. I ran the script as CLI using root, so it's not a user restriction issue.

The only reason that I can come up with, is that PHP is somehow running in a controlled environment? Otherwise the passthru() should at least have worked.

Comment: It's added as a literal directly to the function. chmod($path, 02775) and the other is simply passthru("chmod 02775 '$path'")

Comment: Have you read the [documentation of `chmod()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php)? It clearly states: *"The mode parameter consists of three octal number components"*. It doesn't allow changing the setuid, setgit or the stick bit.

Comment: @axiac the docs state that only when safe mode is enabled: *When safe mode is enabled, PHP checks whether the files or directories you are about to operate on have the same UID (owner) as the script that is being executed. In addition, you cannot set the SUID, SGID and sticky bits.*

Comment: @axiac, I found the solution in the below answer. And PHP's chmod seams to be fully capable of changing the sticky bit, so long as it does not get reset by chown() or chgrp()

Comment: @axiac Yes, I think this is old or mistaken information in the manual. By the looks of the current code, [chmod](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/94b4abdbc4dd1134f345eda0429ce19d999d8fac/ext/standard/filestat.c#L574) just [passes through](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/18750a2238e11edffced0cc5c8c6d159cfd8a781/Zend/zend_virtual_cwd.c#L1621) the provided mask to the underlying system call, and the sticky bit should get through just fine. (Safe mode was removed in PHP 5.4, so that's not very relevant to the documentation or the current PHP source code any more, either.)

Answer (score 0):

Okay found the problem. 
Apprently PHP's chown() and chgrp() functions resets the sticky bit to 0. So chmod() must be the last to be called in order to preserve the permissions.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53665/chown-removes-sticky-bit-bug-or-feature; it's not necessarily just PHP.

Comment: Yes makes sense. PHP's functions is most likely just wrappers around C's functions, which would make this the case for everything relying on those.

Comment: @Daniel B, I do not seem to be able to replicate your solution. All details are [in this new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64247139/how-do-i-set-sgid-in-php). I wonder if you could help....