# How do I set SGID in PHP?

Tags: php, file-permissions, chmod, mkdir

I cannot manage to set the SGID bit from PHP.

I have this directory:

```
  4 drwxrwsr-x 12 www-data mygroup  4096 Oct  7 16:05 mydir
```

Note the SGID bit. So, if I simply create a directory into it from the shell with `mkdir test`, I get

```
  4 drwxr-sr-x  2 myuser   mygroup   4096 Oct  7 16:22 test
```

Note that the SGID bit is inherited. But I would want it group writable (which my `umask 22` does not allow) so I can simply `chmod 02775 test` and I am perfectly happy:

```
  4 drwxrwsr-x  2 myuser   mygroup   4096 Oct  7 16:22 test
```

Now I would like to do the same from a PHP script. Naturally, I would expect this to work:

```
mkdir("/mydir/test2");
chmod("/mydir/test2", 02775);
```

But it does not and I get this instead (the SGID is reset):

```
  4 drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data mygroup   4096 Oct  7 16:30 test2
```

Here are a couple of other useful experiments:

```
mkdir("/mydir/test3");
mkdir("/mydir/test4");
passthru("chmod 02775 '/mydir/test4'");
mkdir("/mydir/test5");
passthru("chmod g+w '/mydir/test5'");
```

The results are

```
  4 drwxr-sr-x  2 www-data mygroup   4096 Oct  7 16:39 test3
  4 drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data mygroup   4096 Oct  7 16:39 test4
  4 drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data mygroup   4096 Oct  7 17:06 test5
```

Interestingly, `mkdir()` alone has preserved the SGID, but `chmod()` resets it, even through `passthru()`.

I know that the PHP manual says for `chmod` that the command expects only three octal digits, but I read also [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51362504/is-php-blocking-the-sticky-bit) and it looks like the manual contains obsolete information and others can affect the SGID. Besides, it should not affect the `passthru()` versions, should it? The same [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51362504/is-php-blocking-the-sticky-bit) mentions something about `chmod()` needing to be "the last to be called" after `chown()` and `chgrp()`, but I am not using any of those.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the only way I could find to obtain the permissions I need is to profit of the correct behaviour of `mkdir()` and avoid calling `chmod()` which appears to reset the SGID bit no matter what. The only way I can think of doing this is to change the *umask* with `umask()`:

```
$myumask = umask(2);
mkdir("/mydir/test6");
umask($myumask);
```

This appears to work fine:

```
  4 drwxrwsr-x  2 www-data mygroup   4096 Oct  9 14:22 test6
```

This leaves me with the issue raised in the note of https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php: that all threads of a multithreaded webserver share the same *umask*, obviously leading to undesired and unpredictable behaviour. Luckily, in my case, I could ascertain that all directory creations are done in a monothreaded context (essentially, on the first test run of a script) and thus I feel safe. Hence, this is a useful workaround but **not** a general solution.

Answer (score -1):

Is this running on a web server, or just as a CLI script? If CLI, user or root?

Also, why directories? SGID is used on program files, to allow a user to run a program/script as another user, like "sudo". Have you tried testing this on files rather than directories?

Comment: @ Daniel B. (1) it is run from a web server. (2) I need SGID set on a directory for the very reason mentioned in the [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#SGID) wiki page: "SGID 2770 on a directory named 'music' owned by the user 'root' and the group 'engineers': A user named 'torvalds' who belongs primarily to the group 'torvalds' but secondarily to the group 'engineers' makes a directory named 'electronic' under the directory named 'music'. The group ownership of the new directory named 'electronic' inherits 'engineers.' For various reasons, I need subdirs to inherit the group.

Comment: @ Daniel B. Note that `mkdir` and `mkdir()` do the right job. The "only" issue is that my umask is 22 and I need to make the directory writable for the group; it is then that the problems arise because `chmod()` does not seem to do the right thing (as I understand it). One solution could be to change the `umask` just before `chmod()` and set it back afterwards. The PHP manual shows this but then recommends not to do it in the Notes of [umask](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php), so I did not try this not to run into problems I do not quite understand....

Comment: Now that I look again in the [umask](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php) I am utterly confused: why the example (deprecated in the Notes) changes the `umask` before `chmod()`?! My understanding is that in a shell the `umask` has only some (minor) effect when specifying the string form of the argument. But this format is not possible in PHP, see [chmod](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php). And, if I search for `umask` in the `chmod()` reference page I find (predictably) no occurrences of it. So, what does the example mean?!

Comment: I cannot edit anymore one of the comments above, but I meant "change the `umask` just before `mkdir()`".